# Load Magento configurable product based on attribute options

Tags: magento

Is there a magento function that exists which will allow me to load a configurable products child product based on the attributes options used.

For example I have the option values for t-shirt color and size, say 10, 45 (option id's) and I want to quickly get the id of the child simple product

Comment: simpleconfigurable extension here : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Matt+Dean/extension/596/simple-configurable-products

Answer (score 7):

For a configurable product `$product`, use this function:

```
$product->getTypeInstance(true)->getProductByAttributes($attributesInfo, $product);
```

where `$attributeInfo` is an array of `$attributeId => $attributeValue` definitions.